Is a query about contextually-appropriate (including vulgar) expressions on topic?
I'm a non-Italian speaker, seeking contextually-appropriate expressions for shocked surprise, even better would be seriously shocked/scared surprise.  (This is for a novel.)  A literal translation of, "Oh, shit!" is doable, but is that colloquial or simply not what an Italian speaker would say?  Is such a question OK here, or close-bait?

Welcome to Italian.SE!
I think this would be an acceptable question: it's about Italian usage, after all, and not simply a translation.
Maybe it would be better to try and make it more general. 
I suggest to add a description of the situations in which the character happens to be shocked or surprised: the context is important for finding the right words and this would perhaps make for increased generality.
